# What to use in place of gooseneck kettle?

Tags: pour-over

To make pour over coffee can I use a cup to pour the water on the grounds? How can I best approximate the proper water temperature? I do have a kettle to boil the water but a cup gives me more control in the process.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two important factors here: **temperature** and **control**.

#### Temperature

Temperature is probably the most important factor here. You don't want the temperature to be too low, when that's the case you won't be able to extract all that you want. You can easily ensure you're not using water that's too cold, either by pouring straight from the kettle (goose-neck or otherwise) or by preheating the pouring vessel (e.g. your pouring cup).

#### Control

Control is important for pour over brews, but it's not absolutely necessary. You can simply use a regular kettle to pour but you'll have less control over the flow rate (how fast water flows out) and where you irrigate the grounds.

---

So it's definitely possible to use a (pouring) cup instead of a goose-neck kettle, just make sure it's pre-heated.

Comment: even if the pouring cup is pre heated it is much thinner and will lose heat as fast as it heats up. just for temperature control, i would prefer using a kettle. gooseneck or not does not really matter in the first place.

Comment: @B.Kemmer it depends a lot on the material. If you have a porcelain pouring cup then it will certainly heat up. Doing so without preheating means some heat of the brew water is lost to the cup, whereas those losses are much less when the cup is preheated. Whether goose-neck is more beneficial depends on what you're comparing it to. If you have a broad spout on your kettle you will have trouble maintaining a steady pour for a few minutes. Of course you can try to compensate for that by pouring in intervals.